# can akka actor capture a specific message in all states without implementing the same code

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor that manages different states e.g:

```
case object Start 
case object Stop
case object Init

class Foo extends Actor {

 def receive: Receive = {
   case Init =>
      doSomeInit()
      context become busy 
      self ! Start
   case Stop =>
      context stop self

  }
}
 def busy: Receive = {
   case Start => 
    doingSomeProcessing()
    context become receive
   case Stop =>
      context stop self
}
}
```

I want to avoid writing the Stop handling code in every state (similar to whenUnhandled in FSM )
is there idiomatic way to do that without using FSM ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `orElse` and move the common messages to separate partial function.
`receive` and `busy` are partial functions. You can compose partial functions using `orElse` as shown in the code below.

*Order is important. So based on the use case do `f1 orElse f2` or `f2 orElse f1` f1, f2 are partial functions*

```
case object Start
  case object Stop
  case object Init

  class Foo extends Actor {

    def common: Receive = {
      case Stop =>
        context stop self
    }

    def receive: Receive = common orElse {
      case Init =>
        context become busy
        self ! Start
    }

    def busy: Receive = common orElse {
      case Start =>
        context become receive
    }
  }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 1 => "one"}
f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = <function1>
scala> val g: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 2 => "two"}
g: PartialFunction[Int, String] = <function1>
scala> val x = f orElse g
scala> f(1)
res9: String = "one"
scala> x(2)
res10: String = "two"
scala> x(1)
res11: String = "one"
```

Comment: thanks , I think you missed 
val x = g orElse f at the REPl example